# Is it possible to change the "NO FILL" white background in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, excel-2016

In Excel the "NO FILL" color it is white, and it is quite painful if you are working for long hours on project with bright white display.

If I change the the background color of the Sheets at the beginning to some darker color, it does't really make any sense, because at the end I can spend hours to "paint" many small parts and pieces to "NO FILL".

Is are there any possibility to change that white displayed "NO FILL" to some dark color (apparently which will be displayed white "no fill" on a standard Excel)? I'm using the 2016 version.

Comment: There is no set way to make the default no fill a different color, but there is a workaround: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T006121_Changing_Excels_Background_Color.html

Answer (score 2):

If you set Excel cells background color to "No Fill", you are defaulting to using the Windows Color and Appearance settings.  So, yes, you can change this setting, but it affects all of Windows, not just Excel.

1. Windows Start Menu, type "change window colors and metrics."
2. Click on the window background containing the text "Window Text".  This is a white area for most users. Alternatively, you can select "Window" from the Item drop-down (combo box).
3. Change the color in the Color 1 drop-down (combo box) to any background color you prefer.
4. Change Color 2 to the default text color.

Alternatively, you may prefer to set the background color for all cells in a workbook.  This is not exactly what you requested, but I don't know why it would not satisfy your needs.
 1. Select all cells via Ctrl+a or click the gray square above row 1 and left of column A.
 2. Right click any cell, which will generate floating menus. Use the paint bucket (fill color) drop-down menu as usual to change the background for the enitre sheet.
3. This may result in you not seeing the drig lines.  To correct this, with all cells selected, right-click any cell, and use the border menu to set All Borders.

If there is a reason the methods above do not meet your needs, let me know.

Comment: Doing the alternative, you are actually encoding in each cell some data (background) which will for instance rise up file size, potentially slow UI.